# Log streams in Azure not picking up my logs

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

Admittedly, I'm a bit rusty with deploying and managing ASP.NET apps to Azure app services. The app I'm deploying won't start and I cannot find any information in any of the AS's blades as to what the problem might be.

So, I decided to rely on poor man's debugging and simply dump a log of startup intel to `ILogger` and then check what ends up in the AS's Log Stream. But nothing shows up; at least nothing that was written to ILogger by my code.

In my startup code I added this:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
});
```

In the App Service "App Service Log" blade I enabled Application Logging (Filesystem) and set Level to `Verbose`.

What am I missing, that causes none of my code's log entries to show up in the log stream?

Comment: What do you see if you change the log level to debug?

Comment: Refer this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749481/i-cannot-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream

Comment: services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            loggingBuilder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
        });
    }

Comment: Log level is set to trace but produces no output.
I tested the suggested setup but also no result. I am running .NET 8 btw.

Comment: I checked the Azure log files and I saw that there is indeed at least one file that corresponds to the setup (prefixed "azure-diagnostics-". But there is also a file prefixed just "diagnostics-", that does contain the output I was expecting from my code. So, how can I make that output get channeled to the Log Stream?

Comment: I am trying to replicate the same,  by adding a logger in HomeController.cs, something like this- public IActionResult Index()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("**********Log from diagnostics");
    _logger.LogInformation("**********Log2 from diagnostics");
    return View();
}

Comment: and my program.cs- var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add logging services
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddDebug();
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.AddLogging();var app = builder.Build();

Answer (score 1):

Event though **Startup.cs** is not required in **`.Net 8.0 Asp.net Web app`**, I added the **`AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics()`** logging in the **Startup.cs**  called it in Program.cs and custom logging message in **HomeController.cs** also edited the web.config after the Web app deployment and when ***I restarted my app the Logs got fetched in the Log Stream*** tab like below:-

**My Startup.cs code:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            loggingBuilder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
        });
    }
```

**My Program.cs code:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**My HomeController.cs:-**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebApplication4.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("**********Log from diagnostics");
            _logger.LogInformation("**********Log2 from diagnostics");
            return View();
        }


        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

After deployment change the **`web.config`** ***`by visiting > Advanced Tools > kudu > Tools > Zip push deploy > Edit web.config like below`***:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication4.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="*" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: xxxxxxfd-bfd39633366c-->
```

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

> Note- If you are not receiving any Logs in Log stream even when the Application logging and Web Server logging is turned On, **Switch it back to off and then switch it to On again.** **You can also Restart your Web app and check the Log Stream tab again**.

[image]

*The same Logs were also visible in the **LogFiles**:-*

[image]

**Reference:-**

[c# - I cannot see logs in Azure Log Stream - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749481/i-cannot-see-logs-in-azure-log-stream)